# Extract html code from a page with PHP to extrapolate some images

Tags: php, html, wordpress, domdocument

I've to create a PDF document from a product details page of my WP site and I've extract all html code from the page to extrapolate img and table tag. 
I installed a plugin to create a PDF document from a page but imagese and tables are not inserted: only the text is inserted into the document.

The plugin is woocommercePrintProduct and I've edited its code to insert images into PDF document also. The function that should be modified is the following:

```
div class="descrizione" style="margin:0 30px;">
            <div class="colonnaSx" style="float:left;width:350px;margin-right:30px">
                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('descrizione_prod') ): ?>
                        <h3>DESCRIPTION</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('descrizione_prod'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('forma') ): ?>
                        <h3>SHAPE</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('forma'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('posa') ): ?>
                        <h3>INSTALLATION</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('posa'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('conduttore') ): ?>
                        <h3>CONDUCTOR</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('conduttore'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('isolante') ): ?>
                        <h3>INSULATION</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('isolante'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('guaina') ): ?>
                        <h3>SHEAT</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('guaina'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('sforzo_massimo_di_tiro') ): ?>
                        <h3>MAX MECHANICAL STRESS</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('sforzo_massimo_di_tiro'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('guainetta') ): ?>
                        <h3>INTERNAL SHEATH</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('guainetta'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="colonnaDx" style="float:right;width:350px;">
                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('marchiatura') ): ?>
                        <h3>MARCHIATURA</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('marchiatura'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('colore') ): ?>
                        <h3>COLORE</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('colore'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

                <div class="pacchettino">
                    <?php if( get_field('tensione_di_esercizio') ): ?>
                        <h3>TENSIONE DI ESERCIZIO</h3>
                        <p><?php the_field('tensione_di_esercizio'); ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

        <?php /*
        <table class="description">
            <?php
            $description = wpautop($this->data->description);
            $description = preg_replace("/\[[^\]]+\]/", '', $description);
            $description = explode('<p>', $description);
            foreach ($description as $value) {
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td  style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                        <?php echo $value ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

        </table>

        */
        ?>

        <div class="description"  style="margin:0 30px;">
            <?php
                $description = wpautop($this->data->description);
                $description = preg_replace("/\[[^\]]+\]/", '', $description);
                $description = explode('<p>', $description); 
                foreach ($description as $value) {
            ?>

                <div class="pacchettino" style="padding-bottom: 20px;margin:0 30px;">
                    <?php 
                        echo $value 
                    ?>
                </div> 

            <?php
            }
            ?>

        </div>


        <?php

        return ob_get_clean();

    }
```

I thought to extract html code from the details product page and then, extrapolate img tag and intert them into the document.

Can you help me, please?

Comment: What is the name of the plugin?

Comment: the plugin is woocommercePrintProduct and I've edited its code to insert images in the PDF document

Answer (score 0):

There are much, much easier solutions for this.

I recommend WKHTMLtoPDF, it is open source, no browser, no app, just command line, extremely simple.
http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html

How to use: 
After installing from the link above
Open CMD prompt 
Type in

```
wkhtmltopdf {website} {filename to save as}
```

Example:

```
wkhtmltopdf http://google.com google.pdf
```

User Manual:
http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

There are numerous other programs and even online tools that can do exactly what you ask at no charge, many are even open source like the one above. There is no point shaving a square peg to fit in a round hole when you can get cylinders for free.